# How does a app know who viewed my whatsapp profile?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I just figured out there are apps available that can see who visited my whatsapp profile. It seems kinda sketchy since on one app I had 3 visitors for today who I did not have contact with for more then 5 years. I belive its fake and just random selected from my contacts. However I also installed an app where they ask to create an account. Im kinda carefull with creating accounts and giving access to all my contacts and everything else I dont know of. But I now wonder how those apps work.

#### How do they know who visited my Whatsapp profile?

I understand how the blue check marks work. And that you can somehow fetch this in an other app. And then say they checked ur profile. But does Whatsapp register who visited? Or who checked the profile picture? Since thats what the apps promise you to know.

I am using android and I once created an android app. I would like to know in basic terms how it works. So I could almost create such an app by myself with just the directions you guys may give me.

Comment: An app like WhatsApp records every single action you do. Be it click a button, swipe, send a message, etc. If you want to record Profile visits, you can do it with the API, added a new row in some table every time a Profile is requested

Comment: @AhmadSattout I have been reading a little in the [API documentation][https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/overview] (if this is the one you mean). But cant really figure out what api call would make this possible. Also can you tell me how you know that they save every action you perform? Is there a source or something where you can see this? Not that I dont belive you, just want to read more about it.